# Where in Shas was the psak din of Rabbi Meir vs. Rabbi Yehuda accepted?

Tags: talmud-gemara, machlokes, tannaim

I think I remember that, in disputes between Rabbi Meir and Rabbi Yehuda, we follow Rabbi Yehuda except in two occasions. Is this correct and where are these two instances?

Comment: A lost ketubah (cf. BT Ket. 56b) and three months of waiting before remarriage (ibid. 60b)? Though another case ruled in accordance with R. Meir is the sale of certain (palm-tree) items to an idolator (Mishna AZ 5:1; cf. comm. of Rambam & Tos. YT).

Comment: @Oliver now that the question has been reopened, you might want to write up your comment as an answer

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103975/why-is-the-halacha-according-to-r-meir-against-r-shimon

Comment: Check Mavo Hatalmud of Rav Shmuel Hanagid, he brings the rules

Answer (score 4):

Ordinarily the *halachah* is not in accordance with R. Meir since, as explained in BT ([Eru. 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.13b.3?with=all&lang=bi)), “his colleagues were unable to ascertain the profundity of his opinion” (Trans., and others hereon, from Sefaria). Indeed, when R. Meir is in disagreement with, for example, R. Yehudah the halachah is in accordance with the latter (cf. @[mbloch’s answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106279/15571)). However, we also have on record that “Shmuel said that the halakha is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Meir with regard to all of his decrees” (BT [Ket. 57a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.57a.2?with=all&lang=bi), cf. also Eru. 47a). Upon consulting a few cases it appears that the *halachah* follows R. Meir in more than two occasions:

1. > The following things are forbidden to be sold to idolaters... Rabbi Meir says: also a “good-palm”, hazab and niklivas are forbidden to be sold to idolaters (Mishnah [AZ 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.5?with=all&lang=bi))

Rambam (Comm., [ibid](https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.5.1?lang=bi)) rules that the halachah is like R. Meir. See Tos. YT ([ibid](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.5.4?lang=bi).).

2. > It is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Meir says: In the case of **anyone who reduces** the amount of the marriage contract to lower **than two hundred** dinars **for a virgin or one hundred** dinars **for a widow, this** marriage amounts to **licentious sexual intercourse**... (BT [Ket. 56b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.56b.8?with=all&lang=bi))

Based on this *baraita*, a particular case of a lost *ketubah* (ibid 57a) was ruled in accordance with R. Meir as his reasoning was enacted as a *gezeira* (decree).

3. > If a man deposited a sum of money with an agent for his daugher, and [after she was betrothed] she says, “I trust my husband”, the trustee must act in accordance with the condition of his trust, the words of Rabbi Meir; Rabbi Yosei says... (Mishnah [Ket. 6:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Ketubot.6.7?with=all&lang=bi))

According to Rav Nachman, the halachah is like R. Meir (BT [Ket. 69b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.69b.10?with=all&lang=bi)). [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.20.14?with=all&lang=bi) decides like Rav Nachman (who disagrees on the authority of Shmuel ruling as R. Yosei).

4. > If one slaughtered the first born and then showed its blemish [to an expert]:Rabbi Judah permits, But Rabbi Meir says: since it was not slaughtered by the instructions of the expert, it is forbidden. (Mishnah [Bekh. 4:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bekhorot.4.3?with=all&lang=bi))

The gemara clarifies that R. Meir’s ruling is a matter of penalty. Rambam (MT, [Bekh. 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.3.4?with=all&lang=bi)), and others - see [KM](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.3.4.1?lang=bi), seemingly equate this to a gezierah and therefore rule in accordance with R. Meir whereas Tosafos (Bekh. [28a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Bekhorot.28a.13.1?with=all&lang=bi) and Betz. [27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Beitzah.27a.14.1?lang=bi)), following R. Ahai Gaon, differentiate between a penalty (קנס) and decree (גזירה) with regard to ruling like R. Meir.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the gemara in [Eruvin 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.46b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that

> Rabbi Ya’akov bar Idi said that Rabbi Yoḥanan said: **In the case of a
>   dispute between Rabbi Meir and Rabbi Yehuda, the halakha is in
>   accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yehuda**

This is picked up by R Aryeh Carmell in his book [Aiding Talmud Study](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0873064283) (p. 74, note 5) where [he writes](https://books.google.de/books?id=Rq-kVjTnlP0C&pg=PA74&dq=dispute%20rabbi%20meir%20rabbi%20yehuda&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYwPmyrenjAhWGB5oKHQeYClQQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=dispute%20rabbi%20meir%20rabbi%20yehuda&f=false)

> **Where Rabbi Meir is named in as a source, and his decision is
>   disputed**, either **by Rabbi Yehuda**, Rabbi Yose, Rabbi Shimon or Rabbi
>   Eliezer ben Yaacov, **the halacha is like his opponent**

@Oliver in his comment to your question above has already mentioned a number of exceptions; I will let him write them up in an answer.